# What are the lowest locking primitives in Linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64

What are the lowest locking primitives in linux. I know about `futex_wait` and `futex_wake`. But futexes can be used for signalling besides locking. What is the lowest locking primitive and where can I find it in the glibc library? Secondly, are the condition variables also based on futexes?

Comment: I'd say the "lowest lowest" is the `LOCK` prefix in the CPU itself, which enables you to perform some operations atomically.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar ... in the *x86-family* CPU ...

Comment: futex_wait is a syscall, that's not in glibc. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: and the pthread locking primitives are implemented with a mixture of futexes and of assembly code (doing things non-expressible in portable C99).

Comment: @KennyTM the question is tagged as `x86-64`, so I just took this as implied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read various documentations on [futex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futex)-es, including [futex(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/futex) and [futex(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/futex.4.html) man pages. You'll learn that pthread locking primitives are implemented with a mixture of futexes and of assembly code (doing things non-expressible in portable C99)

<sup>(as I said in a comment)</sup>

Comment: But are all synchronization objects, such as pthread_mutex_lock, sem_post, sem_wait etc based on futexes or are there other low level primitives too? What about condition variables? Barriers?

Comment: *Everything* is built around the assembly atomic operations. Memory barriers, compare-exchanges, and guaranteed atomic reads/writes ARE the lowest building blocks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "lowest", but locks for different scenarios and purposes and "signalling" is not the right criterion to distinguish different sorts of locks.

- There are locking primitives that preform an active wait, spinlocks,
  that are based on atomic operations. With the venue of C11, these
  aren't even OS features anymore, `atomic_flag` can be used for that.
- The other family of lock primitives suspend the calling thread during
  wait. In linux these are all implemented with a combination of atomic operations and `futex` as work horse
  underneath for the waiting part.

Spinlocks are best used in contexts where you know that the critical phase only a handful of assembler instructions and where an interruption of the critical phase by the scheduler or signals is unlikely. This is the case for much more contexts than many people tend to belief. Therefore the `atomic_flag` is an important new feature in the C language.

The other locks are best used in context where active wait would eat up a substantial part of system resources.